# Need help on how to use onActivityResult() on Adapter Class?

Tags: java, android, adapter, onactivityresult

I tried to return a phone number from a contact list on my adapter class, when i use  `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` I got error.

```
btnContactGift.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                // Show only contacts with phone numbers

intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
                // Start the Contacts activity
                context.startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);

            }
        });





public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_CONTACT :
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI};
Cursor c = conR.query(contactData, projection, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
int nameIdx =c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
int phoneNumberIdx =c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
int photoIdx = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI);
                String name = c.getString(nameIdx);
                String phoneNumber = c.getString(phoneNumberIdx);
                String photo = c.getString(photoIdx);
                if (name == null) {
                    name = "No Name";
                }
                String nwPhone = phoneNumber.replace("+251", "0");

                edtPhoneGift.setText(nwPhone);
                c.close();

                // Now you have the phone number

            }
            break;
    }
 }
```

> Can not resolve method onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)

Answer (score 1):

`onActivityResult()` needs to be implemented on the activity or fragment on which you call `startActivityForResult()`. In your case, that would be whatever activity or fragment is identified by `context` (from `context.startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT)`).

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the call to super `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)`, you don't need that.

Also, you need to change the `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI` in your projection to something else, you can get `Photo.XXX` fields from the `Uri` returned from a Phone Picker intent, only columns within Phone.XXX or implicitly joined to it, you can try using `Contacts.PHOTO_ID` instead.

Comment: thanks but when i delete super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data) i couldn't get the selected contact